# @FeignClient name parameter (service id) with relative url at the end

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I have started using Feign in my spring boot project recently. 
I have a question about scenario when my feign client uses service discovery and load balancing with eureka and ribbon (the target service is spread across the multiple nodes in a cluster). I want to have one feign client interface like this:

```
@FeignClient(name="targetServiceId")
public interface MyFeignClientRelatedToCommonUrlPart {

    @RequestMapping(value="/common-url-part/rest-of-the-url-1", ...)
    .....method signature....

    @RequestMapping(value="/common-url-part/rest-of-the-url-2", ...)
    .....method signature....

         ......

    @RequestMapping(value="/common-url-part/rest-of-the-url-N", ...)
    .....method signature....  
}
```

Is there any way to "mix" the value of the name parameter (targetServiceId) with "/common-url-part" to avoid replacing the same url part in annotation for every method in my interface?

Comment: Not really. If you put `@RequestMapping` on the interface, Spring will think it is a controller, which is not good wither.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `path` property like this:

```
@FeignClient(name="targetServiceId", path = "/common-url-part/")
```

It should do the trick, at least the description seems to be promising: [FeignClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignClient.java).